# Eclipse closes as soon as workbench loads

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, helios

I am having this problem for some weeks now, eclipse starts with splash screen, loads plugins, workbench etc, UI opens and closes immediately. I have tried everything possible, there are no log files generated in .metadata. Problem started with Helios then I installed Juno but still its same. 
I have tried installing JDK 1.6 , 1.7 again but didnt work as well.

What all i have tried :

1) All the possible changes in eclipse.ini, perm size, -vm argument 
2) console with -clean and -clonsoleLog -debug option, no errors , problem
persists
3) system restore to a previous date when Helios was working correctly

Please help me.
Shashank

Comment: Did you try a new empty workspace? There might be something in your workspace that's messing things up.

Comment: Hi Francis, I have tried that. Still not working. The unusual thing is there are no log files generated anywhere. Using CMD i tried running ./eclipse>java -jre plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.jar ..and still same thing happened.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then and accept it so that this will show as answered (and it will better help the next person)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got stuck in the same situation.i managed it by deleting folder metadata in the workspace and it worked fine for me

then follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11983265/1315392) to import all projects

Answer (score 3):

After java update, eclipse will not start because default jdk location has changed. Adding the following lines to eclipse.ini file solved my problem immediately:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
```

I added these lines just before vmargs. It looks like as the following :

```
...
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

For more information on eclipse.ini, visit this the site http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: This was the solution for me after I updated the JDK.

Comment: Thanks. Lots of possible answers to this problem, but this was the one who solved it for me. (Neon on windows 7 here)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working once again ...i found a eclipse folder in C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Eclipse , deleted it along with temp files in Temp folder and magically it has started working. Phew..thanks for your reply.

Ecipse is starting now but UI is completely broken ...and on top of that, I have to delete that folder everytime i have to start eclipse.