# How to import a Java project to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, project

I was trying to export a Java project. I was able to create a JAR file by using the option Export -> Java -> JAR file. I am not able to import this jar file into Eclipse (no import option for java). Am I doing anything wrong here?

Using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Version: Juno Release)

Comment: do you want to import the .jar on the classpath or you want to import the source code into a different workspace?

Comment: import the source code. Along with the .jar files in library

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a simplier way than exporting and importing the jar. Lets assume your project is named MyProject123. Just:

1. Just open the workspace with your file manager,
2. Copy the folder MyProject123 that contains the project and paste it
   in an other workspace.
3. Open eclipse and create a new Java Project named MyProject123

Eclipse will recognize that there is a project with that name in the workspace and will import it. All you have to do is to make refresh (press F5) on the new project.

Answer (score 8):

To be able to import the project back instead of using JAR, try using 'Archive File' as follows.

### Export to Archive

`File -> Export...`

Choose `General -> Archive File` as the export type like so :

[image]

and then,

[image]

### Import back from the above archive

`File -> Import...`

Choose `General -> Archive File` and then set it up as follows :

[image]

Comment: While importing do we select 'Archive' or 'Existing projects into workspace' ?

Comment: @Chillax, choose `Archive` while importing.

Answer (score 3):

Follow follwing Steps :

`Import Project -> JavaEE -> App Client Jar File -> Browse and select jar -> OK`

You are done.

Comment: This works. But how do we make sure that the library jar files are also present along with it? Is it possible?

Comment: And it creates a new folder "appClientModule' under which the packages goes into. Any way of not letting that happen? Thanks

Comment: right click on `appClientModule`-> Refactor -> Rename to whatever you want. FYI : your class files will be under `ImportedClasses` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

File-> import
Now type " existing in the search bar"
Click on "import existing project into workspace"
select root folder of your project

click ok to import

For video help visit 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsMPhZTxiF4

Answer (score 1):

this the step u can apply to do that so.

**Import Project -> JavaEE -> App Client Jar File -> Browse and select jar -> OK**

Answer (score 0):

You can import jar file from `Eclipse File->Import->General->Archive File`

Answer (score 0):

```
File -> Import -> General -> Archive File
```

This will import your project in Eclipse.

Also, you will need to add libs/jars externally by configuring your buildpath.