# how to import source code into Eclipse from a jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I got a `jar` file that is packaged with `source code` in it. I want to load it as a top-level project and start working on the source code. How can I do that in Eclipse?

For example: if I have helloworld.jar, when I import this jar. I want to have the project name as helloworld, with all the packages and src inside it.

I do not want that code on build path.but on my IDE to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directory named "helloworld" and unpack the JAR into that directory:

```
mkdir helloworld
cd helloworld
jar xvf ../helloworld.jar
```

You can then create a project from existing sources and start operating on that. I don't think Eclipse will let you create a project and change files directly in the JAR.

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling with ways to see if eclipse automatically does it. but nevertheless, what you suggested is not very tedious

Answer (score 3):

@eagertoLearn Yes. Eclipse does this in a very easy way than suggest by @Erik Gillespie.

Use **Import from archive file feature** in eclipse. Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11983201/1391924

Supported archive file types:

- *.jar
- *.zip
- *.tar
- *.tar.gz
- *tgz

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the .jar and choose open with -> winrar (or another archiver) and then click  extract.

From there you can import the folder in Eclipse as a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the jar file contents using the following steps:

1. Create a new java project
2. Import jar file using file>import>general>archive file option
3. Move the folder containing source code into the src folder using drag and drop
4. Run the class containing the main method