# How to open this project imported from Github?

Tags: java, git, github, open-source

https://github.com/dwdyer/uncommons-maths

Need to analyze this software for a project, and our group doesn't understand how to get this running. I'm hoping someone here can help! I've imported it to eclipse and tried running a few things but no luck.

Comment: give the errors if you want some help

Comment: @VictorSmt There is no errors we just don't know how to do this.

Comment: is this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983088/how-to-import-a-java-project-to-eclipse) clear?

Comment: @VictorSmt The problem isn't getting the project into Eclipse, it's running the project. We already got it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This project build with Ant. So to run this download Ant https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi or use provided by your IDE (if there is, maybe some plugin is needed too), go to your project root directory (with build.xml file) and type this command in your terminal:
ant all (assuming you have ant in your $PATH)

After successful build go to ./dist directory and run generated jar:
java -jar file-name.jar

Comment: I was able to compile the Build.xml file, and it was recognized as being Ant. However, it throws this error, and i have a JDK installed that compiles etc: 
jar:file:/home/kennyp/git/uncommons-maths/lib/compiletime/uncommons-antlib-0.3.1.jar!/org/uncommons/antlib/antlib.xml:118: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/home/kennyp/git/uncommons-maths/lib/compiletime/uncommons-antlib-0.3.1.jar!/org/uncommons/antlib/antlib.xml:83: Unable to find a javac compiler; 
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.

So I am going to try with the alternative option.

Comment: You need to have JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to your JDK directory.

Comment: it appears to already be pointing there. Did an echo call and it points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

Comment: Sorry, try to set like this JAVA_HOME =  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Comment: kennyp ~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

But, it doesn't seem to change in eclipse.

Comment: Try to reload eclipse, reload terminal. check JAVA_HOME and try manually and in eclipse. You can check which JDK eclipse uses too.

Comment: Have you soved this? If this answer is correct please approve.

Comment: This was not the correct solution. There was a demo.jnlp file that a friend had found and was required to run the project after doing some updates. Thank you though!