# How do I import java project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a total beginner in java and need help. I have file "OOP_Introduction_Examples" and I need to import examples from it in eclipse.

Here is what I have when I open that file:

[image]

What excatly I need to do to open it in Eclipse (Which one of these)? Should I just import -> .project? I tried something, but doesn't look good.

Comment: That looks like it's already an Eclipse workspace. Try opening it as a workspace.

Comment: you can look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983088/how-to-import-a-java-project-to-eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a Java project to Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983088/how-to-import-a-java-project-to-eclipse)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the download of the project so we can double check that it's not corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I put this as an answer.

If you choose "select root directory" you are gonna import a directory which contain the project (files shown in the picture). So, you choose the directory that contains files and folders from the picture (bin, src, .priject ....).

For exemple, if you have the next project directory/file tree, click on myProject directory and valid your choice.

```
myProject
   |-.settings
   |-src
   |-bin
   |-classpath
   |-project
```